# Generate TensorFlow Example Projects

Tags: c++, tensorflow, makefile, installation

I'm trying to generate the TensorFlow Example projects by executing the make command like described here "https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers/library?hl=de" under "Generate projects for other platforms".

I'm executing it just out of the Windows cmd.exe tool. I am entering the line as described: "make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile generate_projects". This generates the error output that "make" is an unknown command.

Previous to that I followed the installation instructions as described here "https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=de".

Why am I not possible to use make? Did I forgot the installation of any other tool? What do I need to use "make"?

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Is your issue is resolved ? Else, Did you executed `make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile generate_projects` in linux ?